# Grails 2.3.7 repository issues

Tags: maven, grails, maven-2, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I am having multiple issues trying to use grails 2.3.7 on a windows machine. It seems that many of the jars present in the dependencies for the grails plugins are not present.

The application is trying to access files from locations which are not valid.

If anyone has any idea, where am I going wrong please reply back.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: which plugins are you using?

Comment: what error message are you getting? are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it from my office, where I have internet restrictions. It worked out when I tried it from home. Thanks anyway